# How to get ajax request in redux?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, request, redux

I'm stupid, I still can't get ajax request in redux. I don't understand, where should I get getState in action. In component, I using connect that link action and reducer. Then I using componentDidMount that call an action in a component. How to get ajax request in redux from server? Help me to understand this disorder. I tried to understand the examples of redux, but it's has no effect. If I start a server, get warning : getDefaultProps is only used on classic React.createClass definitions. Use a static property named `defaultProps` instead.
**Action**

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
export const GET_BOOK_SUCCESS = 'GET_BOOK_SUCCESS';

export default function getBook() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/data",
      dataType: "application/json"
    }).success(function(result){
      return dispatch({type: GET_BOOK_SUCCESS, result});
    });
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```js
import {GET_BOOK_SUCCESS} from '../actions/books';

const booksReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  console.log(action.type)
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_BOOK_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        books: action.result.books,
        authors: action.result.authors
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default booksReducer;
```

**component**

```js
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      console.log(state)
      return {
        books: state.books,
      };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return  bindActionCreators({getBooks: () => getBook(),}, dispatch);
    }

    @Radium
    @connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
    class booksPage extends Component {
      static propTypes = {
        getBooks: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        const { getBooks } = this.props;
        getBooks();
      }

      render() {
        const {books} = this.props;
```

**index.js**

```js
    const store = configureStore({}, routes);

    ReactDOM.render((
      <div>
        <Provider store={ store }>
          <ReduxRouter />
        </Provider>
        <DebugPanel top right bottom>
          <DevTools
            store={ store }
            monitor={ LogMonitor }
            visibleOnLoad />
        </DebugPanel>
      </div>),
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

**configureStore**

```js
function configureStore(initialState, routes) {
  const store = compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      promiseMiddleware,
      thunk,
      logger
    ),
    reduxReactRouter({ routes, history }),
    devTools()
  )(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}

export default configureStore
```

Comment: Can you limit your code to what is important to the question?

Comment: I would gladly, but I don't know where exactly the error